# how to make same function for create and update in laravel controller file for create and update operation?

Tags: php, laravel, function, controller, crud

I already have same form for both.
 my controller below shows two separate function for create and update
 i am new to Laravel framework, and i am working on Address book project.
 for creating new:

```
public function store(Request $request) // for creating new member
{
    request()->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'address'=>'required',
        'phone'=>'required',
    ]);
    Member::create($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('members.index')
        ->with('success','Member created successfully');
}
public function update(Request $request,Member $member) //for updating member info
{
    request()->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'address'=>'required',
        'phone'=>'required',
    ]);
    $member->update($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('members.index')
        ->with('success','Member updated successfully');
}
```

I need to make only one function for both of the operations.thank you in advance.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#other-creation-methods

try using this methods in one function. updateOrCreate for both update and create

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your route

```
Route::post('createanddelete/{id?}','YourController@yourFunction');
```

**By giving ? in route means that optional parameters**

In your controller

```
public function yourFunction($id = null, Request $request)
{
  request()->validate([
    'name' => 'required',
    'email' => 'required',
    'address'=>'required',
    'phone'=>'required',
  ]);

  // write update code
  if($id)
  {
    $member = Member::find($id);
    if($member)
    {
       $member->update($request->all());
       return redirect()->route('members.index')
              ->with('success','Member updated successfully');
    }
  }
  // write create code
  else
  {
      Member::create($request->all());
      return redirect()->route('members.index')
          ->with('success','Member created successfully');
  }
}
```

In the view provider the action of form accordingly.

Hope this will help, but you should write separate function for modular code

Comment: Please upvote this question also, as it might help for others

Comment: tip: your 'return' should be under the 'else' part. So you will undouble that too